# Spring 4 JMS Invoker: could not deserialize service argument from json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-jms

I have two simple test applications: server and client. Server exposes user service with `org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerServiceExporter`:

```
public interface UserService {
    void registerUser(User user);
}

@Component("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Override
    public void registerUser(User user) {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class User implements Serializable {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue userQueue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue("user.queue");
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("JmsMessageType");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsInvokerServiceExporter userServiceExporter(MessageConverter messageConverter, UserService userService) {
        JmsInvokerServiceExporter exporter = new JmsInvokerServiceExporter();
        exporter.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        exporter.setService(userService);
        exporter.setServiceInterface(UserService.class);
        return exporter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Destination destination, MessageConverter messageConverter, SessionAwareMessageListener messageListener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setDestination(destination);
        container.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        return container;
    }
}
```

Client consumes user service with `org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean`:

```
@Bean
public JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean userService(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, Queue queue, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean jmsInvoker = new JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean();
    jmsInvoker.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    jmsInvoker.setQueue(queue);
    jmsInvoker.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    jmsInvoker.setServiceInterface(UserService.class);
    return jmsInvoker;
}
```

On the server side I run into the following exception:

```
java.lang.Throwable: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke
```

After some exploration I found that User object was not deserialized properly from JSON string. Spring tries to call `registerUser` method with `Map` as an argument that contains values from User object passed by client.

Is it possible to have automatic JSON serialization/deserialization of custom objects in case of Spring JMS RPC?

Comment: Are you using a similarly configured converter on the client side? The server is expecting type information (class name) in the `JmsMessageType` property. See `getJavaTypeForMessage()` in the converter.

Comment: @GaryRussell Yes, sure. I omitted part of client config for simplicity. Actually I have the same message converter, queue and connection factory.

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger in `getJavaTypeForMessage()` to figure out why the converter can't figure out the type.

Comment: @GaryRussell I looked at that method and it seems that it works well. Type of message is `org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation`. But arguments list inside the instance of RemoteInvocation contains `Map` instead of `User` object.

Comment: You need to debug in the message converter - if it's converting to a map, it means it's having trouble identifying the type.

Comment: You need a custom MappingJackson2MessageConverter that overrides method convertFromTextMessage() to manually deserialize RemoteInvocation from JSON.

Comment: ...or use default SimpleMessageConverter because your DTO is Serializable.